# Calling libc functions from another shared library in AT&T syntax?

Tags: linux, assembly, shared-libraries, x86-64, att

i was trying to assemble codes below to shared library via gcc.

```
.section .text

.global S_0x400607
.type S_0x400607, @function
S_0x400607:
push %rbp
mov %rsp,%rbp
sub $0x10,%rsp
mov %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
mov -0x4(%rbp),%eax
mov %eax,%esi
lea S_0x400724(%rip),%rdi
mov $0x0,%eax
callq printf
nop
leaveq
retq


.section .rodata

S_0x400724:
.byte 0x25
.byte 0x64
.byte 0x0a
.byte 0x00
```

i used command below in terminal and got errors.

```sh
$ gcc zzz_out.s -shared -fPIC  -o libzzz.so
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccq8FvIT.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then i googled the question and got a seemingly feasible answer in [undefined-reference-to-main-for-shared-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747986/undefined-reference-to-main-for-shared-library). Then i added option `-no-pie`, used commands below and got another error.

```sh
$ gcc zzz_out.s -shared -fPIC -no-pie  -o libzzz.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that the order of options matters. But i used codes in 32-bits like this.

```
.section .text

.globl S_0x8048506
.type  S_0x8048506, @function
S_0x8048506:
push %ebp
mov %esp,%ebp
push %ebx
sub $0x4,%esp
call S_0x80485CC
add $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_,%eax
sub $0x8,%esp
pushl 0x8(%ebp)
lea S_0x8048670,%edx
push %edx
mov %eax,%ebx
call printf
add $0x10,%esp
nop
mov -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
leave
ret

S_0x80485CC:
mov (%esp),%eax
ret

.section .rodata
S_0x8048670:
.byte 0x25
.byte 0x64
.byte 0x0a
.byte 0x00
```

gcc works perfectly and `libzzz.so` generated in current directory.
Sorry if i asked a simple question. I'm totally new in this region.

Comment: You want `call printf@plt`.

Comment: Or `call *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)` in 64-bit code, like `gcc -fno-plt` would emit when compiling C.  See [Unexpected value of a function pointer local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56760086) for some examples.

Comment: I think `-no-pie` is overriding `-shared`, so you're telling GCC to link a position-dependent *executable*, not a shared-library at all.  (ELF shared libraries always have to be position-independent, there's no such thing as a non-PIC `.so`.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! `call printf@plt` works! but why it works well in 32bits assembly codes while in 64bits it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get `` undefined reference to `main' `` with `-no-pie`.

I think `-no-pie` is overriding `-shared`, so you're telling GCC to link a position-dependent *executable*, not a shared-library at all.  (ELF shared libraries aka "shared objects" always have to be position-independent, there's no such thing as a non-PIC `.so`.  Fun fact: PIE executables are another type of ELF shared object.)

---

Unlike when linking a non-PIE executable, `ld` rewrites `call printf` into a call through the PLT for you.  But when linking a PIE or shared library, you have to do it manually.  (Newer `ld` might do this for you, at least in a PIE, but this was a recent change.)

**In 32-bit code**, `call printf` likely assembles and links with a runtime fixup that rewrites the `call rel32` instruction at runtime to be `printf`'s actual address in libc, once it's loaded to a randomized base address.  But that doesn't work for 64-bit code because it might be more than +-2GiB away.  Similar to why [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) after distros made PIE executables the default GCC config.

**Your options for 64-bit code are:**

- **`call *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)`**, like `gcc -fno-plt` would emit when compiling C.
- `call printf@plt` like compilers have historically used.
- non-PIE executable isn't an option; you're making a `-shared` library.

For a NASM-syntax version of this with more detail about what this means, and the machine code, see [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code/52131094#52131094).  Also has some examples at the bottom which include AT&T syntax, of how the linker "relaxes" this to a `call rel32` if you do `call *foobar@GOTPCREL(%rip)` but then `foobar` is defined in the same shared library after all (with "hidden" visibility, not global, so symbol interposition isn't necessary).

See [Unexpected value of a function pointer local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760086/unexpected-value-of-a-function-pointer-local-variable) for some examples of compiler output for a PIE vs. non-PIE executable (the PIE executable code will also work in a shared library.)

`-fno-plt` style of code-gen is probably not worth it in 32-bit mode, where you don't have efficient EIP-relative addressing to reach the GOT, unless you already needed a GOT pointer for something else in this funciton.